# Python HTML Hex code to character and vice versa

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a given HEX code to character and vice versa. I tried HTMLParser escape/unescape but didn't have success.

**INPUT**:

```
storeKey=%7B%22auth_token%22%3A%22MYTOKEN%22%7D
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
storeKey={"auth_token":"MYTOKEN"}
```

and vice versa.

**Python version**: Python 3 (Anaconda)

[HTML Hex Code reference](https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) should work for you:

```
import urllib
print(urllib.parse.unquote('%7B%22auth_token%22%3A%22MYTOKEN%22%7D'))
# '{"auth_token":"MYTOKEN"}'
```

Likewise, [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
import urllib
print(urllib.parse.quote('{"auth_token":"MYTOKEN"}'))
# '%7B%22auth_token%22%3A%22MYTOKEN%22%7D'
```

Comment: Thank you so much...exactly what I was looking for.